# I have a subsidiary menu which is considered the main menu which I would like to make the sticky

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navbar, sticky

I made it fixed so it travels down the page when you scroll and put a high zindex on it to allow it to sit on top of everything else but how do i fix the gap? I can't simply remove the `top: 42px;` because than it wouldn't look right when the page is at the very top. [image: before changing elements]

Here's what it looks like[after changing css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XG8Y.png):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.navbar {
   position: sticky 
}
```

For such a task it is not entirely correct to use fixed, it is better to use sticky

Comment: I added that to my head but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: It moves the menu up really close to the menu above it and when I scroll down it doesn't follow. @Illia Yalovoi

Comment: Illia's solution is correct, but there are a couple of gotchas in terms of how the sticky element is contained. This tutorial might shed some light: https://usefulangle.com/post/107/css-fixed-navigation-bar-during-scroll

Comment: @Djimmr can you help me with my class because it says not to have it wrapped in a container so it's giving me a bit of trouble. I'm having issues. Website is: https://cloudwausauhomes.com/

Comment: @Singleton it looks to me like you are almost there yourself. The tutorial covers everything you need, the only issue is that it looks like you are using Magento, therefore you will have to find a way to code the CSS to work with the tag structure Magento outputs.

Comment: @Djimmr, thanks my friend. I figured it out. It wasn't all that bad but I hardly write frontend code much anymore.  =]